# rdoc report ++ not documented with a yield inside the method

Tags: ruby, rdoc

The document for this method should already include the parameter `number`.

```
# Iterate and do sth with +number+.
def iterate
  yield(number)
end
```

However, `rdoc -C1` still reports something is undocumented.

```
  # ++ is not documented
  def iterate(); end
```

Any idea what the ++ means in the report and what's wrong in the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed bug in rdoc. ++ is just empty parameter name, which appears in method parameters list due to incorrect source code parsing. This happens when you have some method without any arguments, but which yields something.

I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/pull/281) which hopefully fixes this problem completely. Once it gets included into next rdoc version your problem will go away. There is no workaround at the moment, simply ignore such messages.